# How to get data to show up on useState?

Tags: reactjs

```
const { recipeId } = useParams();

const { loading, data } = useQuery(QUERY_SINGLE_RECIPE, {
    variables: { recipeId: recipeId },
});

// THESE CODES HERE SHOULD GRAB THE RECIPE AND LOAD THE PRESET DATA
// INTO THE RESPECTFUL AREAS OF THE FORM
const recipe = data?.recipe || {};
// console.log('recipe');
// console.log(recipe);

let ingredientList = [''];
if (recipe?.ingredients) {
    for (let a = 0; a < recipe.ingredients.length; a++) {
        ingredientList += (recipe.ingredients[a] + '\r\n');
        // console.log(ingredientList);
    }
}

let directionList = [''];
if (recipe?.directions) {
    for (let b = 0; b< recipe.directions.length; b++) {
        directionList += (recipe.directions[b] + '\r\n');
        // console.log(directionList);
    }
}

// THESE NEXT CODES SHOULD, IN MOST BASIC TERMS, USE A USESTATE TO BASICALLY 
// CREATE AN UPDATED RECIPE. SHOULD HAVE THE SAME CODE AS THE ADD/CREATE NEW RECIPE
const [updateRecipe, setUpdateRecipe] = useState({
    title: recipe.title,
    category: recipe.cateogry,
    servings: recipe.servings,
    totalTime: recipe.totalTime,
    ingredients: recipe.ingredients,
    directions: recipe.directions,
    imageid: recipe.imageid
});
```

When console logged, updateRecipe comes up as an object with undefined, how do I get the update recipe to show the object that will later be updated in a form?

Comment: I think Jacobo's answer is on the correct path, have your update recipe start as an empty object, then in a useEffect check for the recipe object and then setUpdateRecipe({...recipe})
Also I think that in your for loops you will want to do ingredientList[0] += and directionList[0] +=.  or you should use .push() if you want to add them to the array and not the empty string in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are not reacting to the state update. If I'm not mistaken (I don't see which libraries you're using), the `useQuery` is requesting something from a GQL API. `data` would be a reactive variable, for which you would have to use the `useEffect` hook to react to this change. So if you add

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 console.log(data)
},[data]);
```

You should get the data once it's fetched from the server, and update the state within the `useEffect` callback function.

Comment: Thanks!! The missing useEffect helped out!!